# Separately aggregate() cyclic condition sequencees

Tags: r, sequence

A data frame contains repetitive sequences of several conditions, for each repetition of condition sequence in column 'condition' I am trying to take the max of corresponding values in neighbouring column 'time_ms':

The data

```
> data.frame( time_ms=sample(20:40,12), condition=replicate(1,c('cond_one','cond_one','cond2','cond2','cond_three','cond_three')) )
       time_ms  condition
    1       22   cond_one
    2       38   cond_one
    3       26      cond2
    4       23      cond2
    5       35 cond_three
    6       39 cond_three
    7       32   cond_one
    8       27   cond_one
    9       30      cond2
    10      34      cond2
    11      20 cond_three
    12      37 cond_three
```

The desired outcome should be ideally containing only the max value per sequence once (unique values only to make further calculations easier):

```
   time_ms  condition   max_time
1       22   cond_one   
2       38   cond_one   38
3       26      cond2   26
4       23      cond2
5       35 cond_three   
6       39 cond_three   39
7       32   cond_one   32
8       27   cond_one   
9       30      cond2
10      34      cond2   34
11      20 cond_three
12      37 cond_three   37
```

A simple `aggregate()` is close:

```
> aggregate(.~condition, data=mydata, max)
   condition time_ms
1   cond_one      38
2 cond_three      31
3      cond2      39
```

but how to expand this further to treat each condition instance separately?

The example is simplified, real data has limitations:

- condition order in data can be random
- condition sequence size is not fixed

Comment: Take a look at [rle](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) for general reference for such problems. BTW, it is better to use `set.seed` when generating MWE using `sample` (or other functions using random seed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydata)`), grouped by the run-length-id of 'condition', we get the row index (`.I`) of the maximum 'time_ms', extract it as a column (`$V1`), use that as 'i', and assign (`:=`) the corresponding value of 'time_ms' to create the new column 'max_time'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(mydata)[, .I[which.max(time_ms)],  by = rleid(condition)]$V1
mydata[i1, max_time := time_ms]
#    time_ms  condition max_time
# 1:      22   cond_one       NA
# 2:      38   cond_one       38
# 3:      26      cond2       26
# 4:      23      cond2       NA
# 5:      35 cond_three       NA
# 6:      39 cond_three       39
# 7:      32   cond_one       32
# 8:      27   cond_one       NA
# 9:      30      cond2       NA
#10:      34      cond2       34
#11:      20 cond_three       NA
#12:      37 cond_three       37
```

NOTE: This will create NA for the missing values instead of blanks (`""`).  By changing it to `""`, it would also change the `class` of the column to `character`.  So, it is better to keep it that way.

Comment: I think they just need the aggregate, something like `setDT(df)[, max(time_ms), by = .(condition, rleid(condition))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think they want to create the column with max only for the corresponding max element in 'time_ms'

Comment: They said `aggregate` almost worked for them, this is why I thought they want something similar

Comment: @akrun how elegant! this saved me hours of work.
The original intention is to maintain the same data structure, helps with visual check on the data and next steps. Don't mind the 'NA' at all, one of next steps would be difference calculation and this 
can be handled
`diff(mydata$max_time[!is.na(mydata$max_time)])`

Comment: Dropping the redundant empty rows is not a bad idea in the real huge dataset, some alternative to consider, thanks @David Arenburg